# How can I change a URL using .htaccess in wordpress within cakephp?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp

I have Integrated multisite wordpress in cakephp . 
here I have first site that is:

1)mydomain.co.uk/news/

and second :

2)mydomain.co.uk/app/webroot/news/help/

now I want 2nd url like mydomain.co.uk/news/help/

so how to do that? any idea ? .htaccess help?

Comment: Have you looked into CakePHP's routes?  What else have you tried / looked into?

Comment: I have tried using .htaccess but nothing working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into [CakePHP Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).  It lets direct a string URL into a Controller/Action among other things.

> Routing is a feature that maps URLs to controller actions. It was
>   added to CakePHP to make pretty URLs more configurable and flexible.
>   Using Apache’s mod_rewrite is not required for using routes, but it
>   will make your address bar look much more tidy.
>
> Routing in CakePHP also encompasses the idea of reverse routing, where
>   an array of parameters can be reversed into a string url. By using
>   reverse routing, you can easily re-factor your applications url
>   structure without having to update all your code.

Comment: Thanks Dave.

Please can you guide me how to write routes for change URL 

From :   mydomain.co.uk/app/webroot/news/help/ 

To   :   mydomain.co.uk/news/help/

Comment: @Er.KT - that shouldn't need to be redirected - mydomain.co.uk/news/help/ should go to the 'help()' action within the `NewsController`.  Unless you don't have `mod_rewrite` on, it will go there automatically without need for `app/webroot/`

Comment: but here news and help are two different site, created using wordpress multisite.

Comment: You'll probably want to just put the two cake sites in separate places, then use routes to handle the URLs that you want.